# How to get user profiles using ROR+linkedin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

hi I am trying to get user profile information like this once the authentication is successful,

```
class LinkController < ApplicationController
  def callback
    client = LinkedIn::Client.new("ddddd", "ffffff")

    if session[:atoken].nil?

      pin = params[:oauth_verifier]
      atoken, asecret = client.authorize_from_request(session[:rtoken], session[:rsecret], pin)
      session[:atoken] = atoken
      session[:asecret] = asecret
    else

      client.authorize_from_access(session[:atoken], session[:asecret])
    end

    @profile = client.profile
    @connections = client.connections

    puts client.profile(:fields => [:positions]).positions 
    puts client.connections
  end
end
```

the result i get is as follows:

```
#<LinkedIn::Profile:0x4a6fdd8>
#<LinkedIn::Profile:0x4a58f30>
#<LinkedIn::Profile:0x4a58af8>
#<LinkedIn::Profile:0x4a58708>
#<LinkedIn::Profile:0x4a583a8>
```

I really don't understand what is this and if the information is correct than how to convery it to user readable,

I am new guy to ROR please help me to get this resolved.

Comment: You have a collection of LinkedIn::Profile objects. Do client.profile.inspect in the console to have a look at their attributes.

Comment: I am sorry since i am new to ROR i don't really understand what you say, Could you please give some example?

Comment: I am sorry it might make you to get annoyed with me. this is what is my view and printed the out put to console. Please help me. <h1>Link#callback</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/link/callback.html.erb</p>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are objects; use the [inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) method to return a human-readable representation:

`client.profile.inspect`